# Grunt ng-annotate copies complete directory

Tags: gruntjs, annotations, minify, ng-annotate

I have configured Grunt to use ng-annotate. What I want is to annotate all .js files in a specific directory and copy them to a new directory when the annotation is finished. However, the complete src folder is copied to the new directory. This is my configuration:

```
 ngAnnotate: {
        options: {
            singleQuotes: true
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: ['./src/modules/*.js'],
                dest: './src/min-safe',
                ext: '.annotated.js',
                extDot: 'last'
            }],
        }
    }
```

This way, I have a min-safe folder with src/modules and the annotated files. How can I just copy the annotated files into min-safe directly?

Answer (score 2):

Grunt's `src` and `dest` options can be confusing, but they are consistent across plugins (or they are, at least, supposed to be). The Grunt documentation explains [how those options can be used](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) to work with files.

Your problem is that you've not specified the `cwd` option, so all `src` matches are against the project's current directory (the `cwd` default). When a `src` file is copied, the directories between the `cwd` and the matched file are included.

If you use this configuration, it should do what you want:

```
ngAnnotate: {
    options: {
        singleQuotes: true
    },
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: './src/modules',
            src: ['*.js'],
            dest: './src/min-safe',
            ext: '.annotated.js',
            extDot: 'last'
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out and let you know if it worked.